# How to add a series specific line y=x to a faceted (or similar) dual-axis chart in Altair?

Tags: python, axis, facet, altair

Any suggestions for how to facet a dual axis chart and then add a line to each chart at `y=x` using Altair? The challenge is that the line `y=x` needs to match the scale of the series specific to data displayed in each faceted chart.

Links:

1. [altair github issue thread on facets](https://github.com/altair-viz/altair/issues/1934)
2. [altair github issue thread on axis display](https://github.com/altair-viz/altair/issues/1342)

Below is the code that reproduces the issue.

```
import altair as alt
from vega_datasets import data

source = data.anscombe().copy()
source['line-label'] = 'x=y'
source = pd.concat([source,source.groupby('Series').agg(x_diff=('X','diff'), y_diff=('Y','diff'))],axis=1)
source['rate'] = source.y_diff/source.x_diff
source['rate-label'] = 'rate-of-change'


base = alt.Chart().encode(
    x='X:O',
)

scatter = base.mark_circle(size=60, opacity=0.30).encode(
    y='Y:Q',
    color=alt.Color('Series:O', scale=alt.Scale(scheme='category10')),
    tooltip=['Series','X','Y']
)

line_x_equals_y = alt.Chart().mark_line(color= 'black', strokeDash=[3,8]).encode(
    x=alt.X('max(X)',axis=None),
    y=alt.Y('max(X)',axis=None), # note: it's intentional to set max(X) here so that X and Y are equal.
    color = alt.Color('line-label') # note: the intent here is for the line label to show up in the legend
    )

rate = base.mark_line(strokeDash=[5,3]).encode(
    y=alt.Y('rate:Q'),
    color = alt.Color('rate-label',),
    tooltip=['rate','X','Y']
)

scatter_rate = alt.layer(scatter, rate, data=source)
```

## Attempted solutions

#### issue: chart is not dual axis (and this doesn't include `line_x_equals_y`)

```
scatter_rate.facet('Series',columns=2).resolve_axis(
        x='independent',
        y='independent',
        )
```

[image]

#### issue: Javascript Error

```
alt.layer(scatter_rate, line_x_equals_y, data=source).facet('Series',columns=2).resolve_axis(
        x='independent',
        y='independent',
        )
```

#### issue: Javascript Error

```
chart_generator =  (alt.layer(line_x_equals_y, scatter_rate, data = source, title=f"Series {val}").transform_filter(alt.datum.Series == val).resolve_scale(y='independent',x='independent') \
             for val in source.Series.unique()) 

alt.concat(*(
    chart_generator
), columns=2)
```

## Goal

1. `scatter_rate` is a faceted (by series) dual axis chart w/ separate scales appropriate for the range of values.
2. each faceted chart contains a line `y=x` that goes from (0,0) to `y=max(X)` value of the individual chart.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by creating your layers as normal, and calling the `facet()` method on the layer chart. The only requirement is that all layers share the same source data; there is no need to construct the facet manually, and there is no need for late data binding for facets in the current version of Altair:

```python
import altair as alt
from vega_datasets import data
import pandas as pd

source = data.anscombe().copy()
source['line-label'] = 'x=y'
source = pd.concat([source,source.groupby('Series').agg(x_diff=('X','diff'), y_diff=('Y','diff'))],axis=1)
source['rate'] = source.y_diff/source.x_diff
source['rate-label'] = 'line y=x'

source_linear = source.groupby(by=['Series']).agg(x_linear=('X','max'), y_linear=('X', 'max')).reset_index().sort_values(by=['Series'])

source_origin = source_linear.copy()
source_origin['y_linear'] = 0
source_origin['x_linear'] = 0

source_linear = pd.concat([source_origin,source_linear]).sort_values(by=['Series'])

source = source.merge(source_linear,on='Series').drop_duplicates()

scatter = alt.Chart(source).mark_circle(size=60, opacity=0.60).encode(
    x='X:Q',
    y='Y:Q',
    color='Series:N',
    tooltip=['X','Y','rate']
)

rate = alt.Chart(source).mark_line(strokeDash=[5,3]).encode(
    x='X:Q',
    y='rate:Q',
    color = 'rate-label:N'
)

line_plot = alt.Chart(source).mark_line(color= 'black', strokeDash=[3,8]).encode(
    x=alt.X('x_linear', title = ''),
    y=alt.Y('y_linear', title = ''),
    shape = alt.Shape('rate-label', title = 'Break Even'),
    color = alt.value('black')
)

alt.layer(scatter, rate, line_plot).facet(
    'Series:N'
).properties(
    columns=2
).resolve_scale(
    x='independent',
    y='independent'
)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @jakevdp. I guess the only thing we're both missing here is `rate` on the dual axis. I'm still trying to figure out how to add it.

Answer (score 0):

This solution builds the desired line at `y=x` scaled for the data on each chart; however, points are duplicated in the merge step and I'm unsure how to add the dual axis rate.

#### Get Data

```
source = data.anscombe().copy()
source['line-label'] = 'x=y'
source = pd.concat([source,source.groupby('Series').agg(x_diff=('X','diff'), y_diff=('Y','diff'))],axis=1)
source['rate'] = source.y_diff/source.x_diff
source['rate-label'] = 'line y=x'
```

#### Create Y=X line data

```
source_linear = source.groupby(by=['Series']).agg(x_linear=('X','max'), y_linear=('X', 'max')).reset_index().sort_values(by=['Series'])

source_origin = source_linear.copy()
source_origin['y_linear'] = 0
source_origin['x_linear'] = 0

source_linear = pd.concat([source_origin,source_linear]).sort_values(by=['Series'])
```

#### Merge Linear Data

```
source = source.merge(source_linear,on='Series').drop_duplicates()
```

#### Build Charts

```
scatter = alt.Chart().mark_circle(size=60, opacity=0.60).encode(
    x=alt.X('X', title='X'),
    y=alt.Y('Y', title='Y'),
    #color='year:N',
    tooltip=['X','Y','rate']
)

line_plot = alt.Chart().mark_line(color= 'black', strokeDash=[3,8]).encode(
    x=alt.X('x_linear', title = ''),
    y=alt.Y('y_linear', title = ''),
    shape = alt.Shape('rate-label', title = 'Break Even'),
    color = alt.value('black')
)
```

#### Manually Facet Charts

```
chart_generator =  (alt.layer(scatter, line_plot, data = source, title=f"{val}: Duplicated Points w/ Line at Y=X").transform_filter(alt.datum.Series == val) \
             for val in source.Series.unique())
```

#### Combine Charts

```
chart = alt.concat(*(
    chart_generator
), columns=3)

chart.display()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This solution includes the rate, but isn't a dual axis w/ `Y` on one axis and `rate` on the other.

```
import altair as alt
from vega_datasets import data
import pandas as pd

source = data.anscombe().copy()
source['line-label'] = 'x=y'
source = pd.concat([source,source.groupby('Series').agg(x_diff=('X','diff'), y_diff=('Y','diff'))],axis=1)
source['rate'] = source.y_diff/source.x_diff
source['rate-label'] = 'rate of change'
source['line-label'] = 'line y=x'

source_linear = source.groupby(by=['Series']).agg(x_linear=('X','max'), y_linear=('X', 'max')).reset_index().sort_values(by=['Series'])

source_origin = source_linear.copy()
source_origin['y_linear'] = 0
source_origin['x_linear'] = 0

source_linear = pd.concat([source_origin,source_linear]).sort_values(by=['Series'])

source = source.merge(source_linear,on='Series').drop_duplicates()

scatter = alt.Chart(source).mark_circle(size=60, opacity=0.60).encode(
    x=alt.X('X', title='X'),
    y=alt.Y('Y', title='Y'),
    color='Series:N',
    tooltip=['X','Y','rate']
)

line_plot = alt.Chart(source).mark_line(color= 'black', strokeDash=[3,8]).encode(
    x=alt.X('x_linear', title = ''),
    y=alt.Y('y_linear', title = ''),
    shape = alt.Shape('line-label', title = 'Break Even'),
    color = alt.value('black')
)

rate =  alt.Chart(source).mark_line(strokeDash=[5,3]).encode(
    x=alt.X('X', axis=None, title = 'X'),
    y=alt.Y('rate:Q'),
    color = alt.Color('rate-label',),
    tooltip=['rate','X','Y']
)

alt.layer(scatter, line_plot, rate).facet(
    'Series:N'
).properties(
    columns=2
).resolve_scale(
    x='independent',
    y='independent'
).display()
```

[image]